# How can I show content relevant ads using DoubleClick For Publishers (DFP) like Adsense does?

Tags: javascript, adsense, double-click-advertising

I have a single page application that uses AJAX to change the content. Its a content rich site with broad categories.

I want to show ads that are highly related to the content so they are useful and relevant for the user.

Adsense [does not allow](https://developers.google.com/adsense-for-ajax/) you to use AJAX to refresh the ads.

DFP for small business allows you to use the `refresh()` JS function to reload the ads.

The question is:

- Does DFP show relevant ads based on the pages *current* content?

  - If not, how can I show content relevant ads?
  - Would I define a hierarchy of [ad slots](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/177203?hl=en) that match the categories on my site and hope the advertisers/system places the relevant ads in those slots?

Thanks!